# Retrieve only associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to find out the records which are at least associated to any one of the records.

I've this relationship:

```
Class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
end

Class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_leaders, through: :allocations
  has_many :workers, through: :allocations
end
```

I need to find out only those services which has at least one worker or one teamleader associated to it. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you could do this without writing some SQL, but this is how I would have done it:

```
Service.includes(:team_leaders, :workers).where('team_leaders.id is not null OR workers.id is not null').references(:team_leaders, :workers).all
```

**Edit:** adding .references (see comments below)

Comment: Could you give me the executed SQL query when running this code ?

Comment: it is giving the deprecation warning. Although my mistake it was.. now it works

Comment: Did you try to add `.references(:team_leaders, :workers)` at the end of the query (it's a new restriction from Rails 4) http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references and http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Comment: I don't know why they added that in rails 4 but probably to explicitly confirm that the table exists (as the WHERE clause is a string), but i'm not sure.

Comment: Hey how would i do if i need to restrict category also. I mean to say i dont want to show category also if the service associated to it has no team_leaders or workers.?

Answer (score 1):

c = Category.first

```
c.services.each do |service|
 if Allocation.exists?(:service_id => service.id)
   puts service.name
   puts service.service_name
 end
end
```

It will list only those services which has associated workers and team_leaders.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
Service.joins(:team_leaders, :workers).where('team_leaders.id is not null or workers.id is not null')
```